# Make HTML table always fit screen both vertically and horizontally, without scroll bar

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make sure that HTML <table> always fits screen both in width and height? And no scroll bar must appear.

For example this table:

```
    <style>
        p {
            font-size: 9px;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        body,
        td,
        th {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: 9px;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table tr td {
            width: 50%;
            position: relative;
        } 

        table {
            max-height: 40vw;
        }

    </style>
    <table width="88%">
        <thead>
        <tr style="border: none!important;">
            <th colspan="2" style="border: none!important;">
                logo
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <p>title </p>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If width is decreased enough, height will increase and scroll bar will appear. In my case, instead of height increasing, table itself must fit into height and width of screen.

Edit: This table used in mobile app, and it has a preview button. When pressed, a popup with a size that is half of a screen shows up and my table must fit in this box. Moreover, when pressed "view" button table shows up in a full screen mode. What i am failing to achieve is that in a preview mode, half of a table shows up, and there is no scroll bar over here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood you correctly because of the strange styles in your example, check this code maybe it is what you are looking for:

```
<style>
  body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  table {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 2px;
  }

  body,
  td,
  th {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 9px;
  }

  th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  table tr td {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
  }

  .logo-top {
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .logo-bottom {
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 55px;
  }

  hr {
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }

</style>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr style="border: none!important;">
    <th colspan="2" style="border: none!important;">
      logo
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
      <p>title </p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        asdaspodiasdkas kajdklsaj kldlasj kasl
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry if problem was unclear, I deleted uneccessary styles and I added more information.